# BI publisher - chart error in Oracle APEX output excel by using rtf template layout

Tags: excel, oracle-apex, rtf, bi-publisher, oracle-apex-5

BI Publisher Enterprice edition
APEX 5, APEX 5.1 - integrated in BI Publisher through instances
Microsoft excel 2013

I create bi publisher rtf template with chart for my reporting. Then I use it in APEX layout. But when I want to print this layout in excel via APEX , the CHART not displayed in this file.
It give follow error:

[image]

In addition i would like to point that when I print this layout in word or pdf, no errors will be displayed.

Can anyone help me to fix this issue!

Comment: I think template needs to be designed in excel using BI publisher Add on 
Please check this link which can help you https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/bi.1111/e22254/create_excel_tmpl.htm#BIPRD3389